# How do I merge a snapshot in Hyper-V Manager?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hyper-v

I have a VM using Hyper-V on Win Server 2008. I'm using the "Now" snapshot, I want to merge everything so I have only one VM with no snapshots.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcR9P.png]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is to delete each of the snapshots (The one from 1/2010 and 6/2012) and then shutdown your VM.  Hyper-v will merge the AVHD files into the original parent VHD and you will have just the one VHD file at the end.

However ... there are a few things you need to be aware of.

1. Depending on how large your AVHD files are, the merge process may take quite a bit of time.  I can see from your screenshot that the original snapshot was taken in January of 2010 so I'm sure the AVHD file from that snapshot may be quite large.
2. Do NOT turn on the VM until the merge is complete!  The GUI interface will not provide you any status on that.  You will need to look at the original VHD file size and date / time stamp to see when it stops changing.
3. If you have the time and space, I would highly recommend that you shutdown the VM and export it before deleting the snapshots just in case you encounter any kind of error.  Store this in a safe place in case you need to "revert" back to it (by copying it back and doing and import).

Comment: You are very welcome!